# MySql consulta anidada

Tags: mysql, sql

- Tengo que consultar 4 tablas de una base de datos en mysql
- De 3 tablas necesito sacar toda la información con un where
- De la cuarta solamente tomar el último registro que se ingresó en la columna.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
SELECT convenio.nit_Fuente, fuentes.nom_Fuente, convenio.nit_asociado, asociados.Nom_asociado, asociados.Apell_asociado
FROM `convenio` 
LEFT JOIN `fuentes` ON (convenio.nit_Fuente = fuentes.nit_Fuente)
LEFT JOIN `asociados` ON (convenio.nit_asociado = asociados.nit_asociado)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT recibo.num_recibo, MAX(recibo.num_recibo
            FROM recibo                             )
WHERE convenio.nit_asociado = '101244561'
```

Comment: Trata de leer esta pregunta como si la hubiera hecho otro. Entenderías algo?

Comment: espero asi este mejor explicado

Comment: Cuál es la clave para vincular Recibo con alguna de las otras tres tablas?

Comment: no tiene una llave como relacionarla tabla recibos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma En que lo solucione fue

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(recibo.num_recibo) 
    FROM recibo ) as NumRecibo, Con.nit_Fuente, Fue.nom_Fuente, Con.nit_asociado, Aso.Nom_asociado, Aso.Apell_asociado 
    FROM convenio Con 
    LEFT JOIN fuentes Fue ON (Con.nit_Fuente = Fue.nit_Fuente) 
    LEFT JOIN asociados ASO ON (Con.nit_asociado = Aso.nit_asociado)
 where Con.nit_asociado = '101244561'
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto a ver

```sql
SELECT convenio.nit_Fuente,
       fuentes.nom_Fuente,
       convenio.nit_asociado,
       asociados.Nom_asociado,
       asociados.Apell_asociado,
       recibo.num_recibo
  FROM `convenio`,
       `fuentes`,
       `asociados`,
       (SELECT recibo.num_recibo,
               MAX(recibo.num_recibo)
          FROM recibo
       )
 WHERE convenio.nit_Fuente   = fuentes.nit_Fuente
   AND convenio.nit_asociado = asociados.nit_asociado
   AND convenio.nit_asociado = '101244561'
```

Comment: no me arroja un error indicando que Cada tabla derivada debe tener sus propios alias

Comment: intente esto SELECT a.nit_Fuente,
       b.nom_Fuente,
       a.nit_asociado,
       c.Nom_asociado,
       c.Apell_asociado,
       r.num_recibo


  FROM convenio a,
       fuentes  b,
       asociados c,
       (SELECT recibo.num_recibo,
               MAX(recibo.num_recibo)
          FROM recibo r
       )

 WHERE a.nit_Fuente   = b.nit_Fuente
   AND a.nit_asociado = b.nit_asociado
   AND a.nit_asociado = '101244561'